# ctx request body is undefined with nodejs

Tags: node.js, request, koa

I have a problem, when I post my form, i can't get what is in my post in my API.

this is my post with axios in react :

```
onSubmit = () => {
    let data = {
        nickname: this.state.nickname,
        password: this.state.password
    }

    axios.post("/api/user/login", { data })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("res from api is => ", res.data);
    })
}
```

and this is in my API :

import koaBody from "koa-body";

```
const   app = new koa();
const   router = new Router();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(koaBody());

router.post("/api/user/login", async(ctx) => {
    console.log("body is => ", ctx.request.body);
    ctx.body = "ok";
});
```

the problem is ctx.request.body is always undefined...
Can you tell me why ?
I tried with router.get and I have no problem, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the body parser *before* the router, otherwise the router will get to handle the requests before the body contents are parsed:

```
app.use(koaBody());
app.use(router.routes());
```

Comment: Well okay thx, didn't know that the order matters !
but now you said it it seems obvious to me.
Thanks